# How to fix "Unable to resolve service for type" error?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to create my first ASP.NET Core Web API. Here is the github url: https://github.com/saduni-udeshika/EAD_Ticket_Booking_Service.git

Here are my code files - `Program.cs`:

```
using TicketBookingService.Services;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Register your services here
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITrainService, TrainService>();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

`TrainController.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TicketBookingService.Models;

namespace TicketBookingService.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/trains")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TrainController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ITrainService _trainService;

        public TrainController(ITrainService trainService)
        {
            _trainService = trainService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateTrain(Train train)
        {
            var createdTrain = _trainService.Create(train);
            return Ok(createdTrain);
        }

        public interface ITrainService
        {
            Train Create(Train train);
        }

    }
}
```

`TrainService.cs`:

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using TicketBookingService.Models;

namespace TicketBookingService.Services
{
    public class TrainService : ITrainService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<Train> _trainCollection;

        public TrainService(IConfiguration config)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(config.GetConnectionString("TicketBookingApp"));
            var database = client.GetDatabase("TrainBookingDB");
            _trainCollection = database.GetCollection<Train>("trains");
        }

        public Train Create(Train train)
        {
            _trainCollection.InsertOne(train);
            return train;
        }
    }

    public interface ITrainService
    {
    }
}
```

This is the project's folder structure:

[[image: Folder structure1]

I get this error:

[image]

Request body

```
{
  "id": {},
  "trainName": "Udarata Manike",
  "trainNumber": "01"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Program.cs, you register the `ITrainService` from the namespace `TicketBookingService.Services`.

While in your `TrainController`, it tried to get the `ITrainService` with the namespace `TicketBookingService.Controllers.TrainController` from the dependency injection which does not exist in DI.

1. You should define the complete interface in TrainService.cs.

```cs
public interface ITrainService
{
    Train Create(Train train);
}
```

2. Remove the `ITrainService` from the `TicketBookingService.Controllers.TrainController` and add a reference `TicketBookingService.Services`.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TicketBookingService.Models;
using TicketBookingService.Services;

namespace TicketBookingService.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/trains")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TrainController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ITrainService _trainService;

        public TrainController(ITrainService trainService)
        {
            _trainService = trainService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateTrain(Train train)
        {
            var createdTrain = _trainService.Create(train);
            return Ok(createdTrain);
        }
    }
}
```